# Possibility of multiple CAsyncSocket servers and clients linked with a single MFC modal Dialog

Tags: mfc

In one of my MFC application, I've one CAsyncSocket derived class and one modal dialog. Socket Event handlers (e.g. OnAccept() OnReceive()) are linked with the relevant dialog member functions of the dialog. The application has two Socket servers; one of which has to serve only one client and other has to serve multiple (say 4/5 clients). The application also has a socket client which has to connect to a server. Currently, one of the server sockets (which handle only one client) is an instance of CAsyncSocket derived class. The server servicing multiple clients is a blocking socket which accepts client connections and service them in different threads. The client socket in my application is also a blocking socket running in another thread.

If I want both the servers and the client of my application to be CAsyncSocket and link with the single dialog:

1. Is the approach correct and feasible ?
2. What is the best way to define OnReceive() and OnSend() members of the dialog so that every server and client can send/receive messages in time and source of the messages can be distinguished properly.
3. Is there any possibility of congestion in OnReceive() function; if so what's the remedy?
4. If the design I want to implement is not feasible with a single dialog, what is the right way to implement it?

Any help on this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAsyncSocket is a non-blocking socket, so your statement that some of the sockets are blocking needs clarification. The socket event handlers (OnAccept, OnReceive, ...) must be in a class derived from CAsyncSocket. But you can have those handlers call functions in the dialog if you like. Is that what you mean by link?

When you create a socket object you can pass its constructor an identifying number that it stores in a member variable. You can also pass a pointer to the dialog. Then when it calls the dialog from OnReceive it can pass that identifying number back to the dialog so the dialog can distinguish what the source is.

OnReceive will not have congestion: The notifications and the socket data are all queued so they wait until you process them. If you are very slow the TCP/IP logic will eventually pause the sender until you process whatever it has queued.

Because CAsyncSocket is a non-blocking socket it is feasible to handle many of them from just one dialog. There is no need for multiple threads and threading will add unnecessary complexity and problems. You should get it all working in the main thread first.

Comment: I'm using 2 socket servers. One is non-blocking CAsyncSoket which handles only one client. Another one is blocking socket which handles 4/5 clients; this blocking socket listens in a worker thread and in a loop it accepts connections and for each connection it creates a worker thread to handle a client. Yes the first server class is derived from CAsyncSocket and socket event handlers in turn calls related functions in the dialog. Now I want to make the second server non-blocking using CAsyncSocket. Your explanation sounds, I can handle 2 servers and 1 client from a same dialog as I expected.